# How do I distinct different values being content of text() in XPath for existsNode?

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, xpath

I have a problem with extracting all possible values stored under a specific XPath under one of my XMLType columns in Oracle database.

I tried existsNode, and it works fine returning only XMLs with content I specified (product_1) but I need my query to return all values that occur in my table under the specified XPath.
I know I need to use select distinct, but not sure how should I build my query to make it work.

Currently I am here:

```
select distinct (my_table) where 
existsNode(my_table,'/warehouse/shelf[productId="product_1"]','xmlns="xmnls_path"')
=1;
```

Comment: A sample XML document and expected result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select distinct extractvalue( value(tags), 'shelf/data/text()') 
from table( xmlsequence( xmltype( 
   '<warehouse>
        <shelf productId="product_1">
            <data>bla1-bla1</data>
        </shelf>
        <shelf productId="product_1">
            <data>bla2-bla2</data>
        </shelf>
        <shelf productId="product_1">
            <data>bla2-bla2</data>
        </shelf>
        <shelf productId="product_2">
            <data>bla3-bla3</data>
        </shelf>
   </warehouse>' 
   ).extract('warehouse/shelf[@productId="product_1"]'))) tags
```

or if you want distinct from all rows:

```
select distinct extractvalue( value(tags), 'shelf/data/text()') val 
from my_table, table( xmlsequence( 
    xmltype( my_table.xmlclobcolumn ).extract('warehouse/shelf[@productId="product_1"]')
)) tags
```